# Trying to make a picturebox accept a int as number

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to do the following action with pictureboxes:

Search for a picturebox that has a special image, my method for this returns a number of the box that has this image.

Example:

```
if (picturebox1.Tag == "special") {
    return 1; //returns value 1 as in picturebox1 contains it.
}
```

Now when I click on pictureBox2 I want it to switch with the picturebox that contains the special picture (I have a total of 10 pictureboxes with pictures, only one box contains a special one)

Click event on picturebox2:

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    performSwitch(2); //2 meaning picturebox "2"
}
```

Method it calls:

```
public void performSwitch(int pictureBoxWaarde)
{
    switch (pictureBoxWaarde)
    {
        case 2:
            pictureBox10.Image = pictureBox2.Image; //else picture overwrites
            pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
            pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox10.Image;
            break;    
    }
}
```

This code works however I dont want to make TONS of if-else statements for every combination there is.. So to make it 'smart' I will need something like this:

```
public void performSwitch(int pictureBoxWaarde)
{
    switch (pictureBoxWaarde)
    {
        pictureBox10.Image = pictureBox2.Image; //else picture overwrites
        pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox"+findBlackBox+".Image;
        pictureBox"+findBlackBox()+".Image = pictureBox10.Image;
        break;    
    }
}
```

If this would work it would get the special box number and work without the need of lots of if-else. How would I do this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you please tell me how I would use this code in my example? Thanks!

Comment: In the event private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) the sender is the pictureBox2, if you cast it to PictureBox you can use as source for set to pictureBox10

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but you can always find a control by its name.

Let's say that you have a variable `string m_specialPictureBoxName;` that always contains the name of the current special picture box, you could do the following:

```
public void performSwitch(int pictureBoxWaarde)
{
    // Get current special picture box
    PictureBox currentSpecial = this.Controls.Find(m_specialPictureBoxName, true) as PictureBox;

    // Get new special picture box
    m_currentPictureBoxName = String.Format("pictureBox{0}", pictureBoxWaarde);
    PictureBox clicked = this.Control.Find(m_currentPictureBoxName, true) as PictureBox;

    // Swap images
    Image temp = currentSpecial.Image;
    currentSpecial.Image = clicked.Image;
    clicked.Image = temp;
}
```

Also I'm swapping the image without using the temporary `pictureBox10` assignment - I'm not sure whether you want `pictureBox10` to get the image. If you do, you can replace it with your previous code instead of the `Image temp = ...`line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign all the PictureBox event handlers to a single method.
2. Write the method like this

   ```
   private void ApictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var clickedPicture = sender as PictureBox;
       // iterate through all picture controls of the current form
       for (var pic in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())  
           if (pic.Tag=="special")
           {
              var temp = clickedPicture.Image;
              clickedPicture.Image = pic.Image;
              pic.Image = temp;
           }
   }
   ```

For the first step, you can either do it manually, or use a similar loop to assign the event handlers in the form constructor.